# Is this a good way to explicate Skolem's Paradox?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Skolems Paradox shows an ostensible conflict between Cantor's Thoerem (**CT**) and the downward Löwenheim–Skolem Theorem (**ST**).

**CT**: for any set $A$, the powerset of $A$, $P(A)$, has a strictly greater cardinality than $A$.  Cardinality is in terms of bijections: two sets have the same cardinality iff there exists a bijection between them.  A set $A$ is *countable* iff there exists a objection between $A$ and the set of naturals $\omega$.  Since (by **CT**) no function surjects $\omega$ onto its powerset, we learn that $P(\omega)$ is uncountable.  Thus **CT** generally tells us some sets are uncountable.

**ST**: If a countable first-order theory has an infinite model, it has a countable model.  The standard axiomatization of set theory, ZFC, is such a theory.

Assume ZFC has a model (which must be infinite).

By **ST**, ZFC has a countable model .

By **CT**, we can deduce the existence of uncountable sets from ZFC.

Therefore, there must be some set *A* ∈  such that  satisfies $A$ is uncountable.  That is, there is no bijection $f \in$  between $A$ and $\omega$.

However, since  has a countable domain, there are only countably many elements available to be members of *A*.

Thus A appears both countable and uncountable.

---

Some good links I found:
1. [How did first-order logic come to be the dominant formal logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2617/how-did-first-order-logic-come-to-be-the-dominant-formal-logic/2618#2618) (and comments)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed $\mathfrak M$ sees only a small fraction of the universe, in particular he does not see the bijection between $\omega$ and itself, or between $\omega$ and some of the members of $\mathfrak M$.

However it is perfectly fine to have a model which is countable and has elements which are uncountable.

If you start by taking the real numbers and using it to generate a countable model, you will end up with a countable model of ZFC (of course it would not know of its own countability) in which there is a *really* uncountable set.

Now recall that $\mathfrak M\models A\text{ is countable}$ if and only if there is $f\in\mathfrak M$ which is a bijection between $A$ and $\omega$. If $\mathfrak M$ does not know about such $f$, $\mathfrak M\models A\text{ is uncountable}$. This is the heart of internal-external points of view.

If, on the other hand, we require $\mathfrak M$ to be transitive then every element of $\mathfrak M$ has to be countable as well (since it is a subset of $\mathfrak M$ by transitivity).

Comment: I changed the OP a bit, is it OK?  I fear "That is, _A_ in  is (at most) countable" might be wrong UNLESS I stipulated that  was transitive.

Comment: @pichael: It is fine, however as long as you do not assume that $\frak M$ is transitive there is no guarantee that every element of $\frak M$ is countable.

Comment: So basically you have been saying that my explanation assumes that $M$ is transitive.  What would I have to add/subtract from my explanation to include non-transitive models of ZFC?

Comment: @pichael: If you look at the Skolem-Lowenheim theorem you will see that it does not only guarantee us a countable model, but also it allows us to point at a certain element and ensure that this element would be in the model. Now suppose we have a model in which there is a truly uncountable set $A$; we can consider the countable model in which $A$ is a member. Obviously this model cannot be transitive, as that would imply $A$ is *also* a subset of that model, which is a contradiction. So you have $A$ which both the universe and the countable model agree is uncountable...

Comment: I thought we would have to distinguish between an $A^M$ and $A^V$, where according to $V$ $A^M$ is obviously (at most) countable, and where according to $M$ $A^M$ _appears_ uncountable (as there is no relevant bijection).  $A^M$ is a proper subset of $A^V$ that includes only the members of $A^V$ that M recognizes (since $M$ views itself as a proper class and can recognize no sets outside itself).  That's what I have been thinking.

Comment: No, the *set* $A$ is the same *set*. The cardinality of the set changes. It may be the case that the set has some specific role (being $\omega$, being $\omega_1$, being $\cal P(\omega)$, etc.) which may also change between models. However as *sets* these are the same, especially when you take submodels of "good" models (i.e. transitive and well-founded models, which may be very large and not just countable).

Comment: I just majorly edited the question.  What I wrote is pretty much exhaustive of what I understand about Skolem's Paradox.  The talk of transitive models, etc., I have only the slightest handle on, if any at all.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is the following correct? The "paradoxical" statement that there are uncountable sets in countable models of ZFC must be said from **at least** two perspectives.  If $M$ is a countable model of ZFC, then as we have discussed, it can't say of itself that it is uncountable.  However, $M$ is certainly saying that some set $A\in M$ is countable. Thus there are **at least** two perspectives.  The reason why I add "at least" is because $M$ can be countable from any model $N$'s perspective that contains a bijection between $M$ and $\omega^N \in N$.

Comment: @pichael: I'm not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: Skolem's Paradox is usually surprising, I suppose, because people initially assume it is being said from a single, absolute perspective.  I'm trying to say that if $M$ is a model of ZFC, then the paradoxical statement—-_there are uncountable sets in countable models of ZFC_--must necessarily be said from two perspectives.  Once someone understands these two perspectives, the paradox goes away.  "$M$ is countable" is said from an external perspective on $M$, while "M satisfies $A$ is uncountable" is obviously said from $M$'s _inside_ perspective.

Comment: @pichael: Yes, that way it makes sense. I suppose it's the late hour that's getting to me, but the first comment is very difficult to understand. The second comment, however, is crystal clear.

Comment: I was just seeing if it was said from ONLY two perspectives or from AT LEAST two perspectives.  I was going for the latter in the "unclear" statement because $M$ may be countable from many different model's perspectives just in case they have a bijection between M and their set of naturals.

Comment: @pichael: Yes, $M$ itself may be countable from the aspect of different models.

Answer (score 4):

A set is countably infinite if it is in bijection to $\mathbb{N}$. If you have a countable model, a set can be uncountably from the "point of view" of the model simply because the model doesn't contain the bijection. So the model doesn't see the bijection, and a set is seen as uncountable.

Comment: Can I give a kind of example for your comment: Let M be a model that satisfies "A is countable."  As you say, this just means there is a bijection in M consisting of N and A.  Let's throw away all such bijections between A and N and call this new model M'.  Thus M sees A as countable, M' sees A as uncountable.

Comment: @pichael: Of course you have to be careful when you say such things. If $A$ is a set which is provably countable (for example, $\omega$ itself) then $M'$ would not be a model of ZFC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I must be missing something crucial here, as that is not immediately obvious to me.  What is M' not satisfying?  Pairing?

Comment: @pichael: $\omega$ itself is missing. It is definable (as an object) from ZFC therefore in every model we need to have something which acts as that set. Indeed it could be a different set. However if you require $M'$ to be a submodel of $M$ then $\omega$ must remain the same.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: what if A was the rationals? or integers?

Comment: @pichael: You will note that I refrain from using $\mathbb N$. This is because $\mathbb N$ is a mathematical idea which is interpreted often as a model of PA which in ZF is interpreted canonically as $\omega$ along with ordinal operations. The same goes for $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$ and so on. All of these can be interpreted as *any* countably infinite set. $\omega$, on the other hand, is a very concrete set in ZFC - it is the collection of finite ordinals. And yes, everything definable from $\omega$ also has to stay if you want $M'$ to be a submodel.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: what does "everything definable from w" mean?  My guess is that you're saying in order to be a model of ZFC, N, Z, Q, etc. all have to be in the model (as these are "definable from" w?).  But, is the bigger picture comment here that I can't throw away the bijections as carelessly as I did while expecting M' to still be a submodel of M?

Comment: @pichael: It means sets which can be defined from $\omega$. For example the set of finite non-zero ordinals; the ordinal $\omega+1$; the set of ordinals which are decomposable in multiplication; etc.

Comment: @pichael: Note that the natural numbers and the integers are both countable. You can define a binary operation $\dot+$ such that $(\mathbb N,\dot+)$ would be isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z,+)$. You may want to begin with understanding what does it mean for something to be definable. Perhaps start by reading [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks for the link and the help.  I'll have to check it out tomorrow...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Quick question though about the OP: is this an OK way to explain Skolem's Paradox?  Anything wrong? missing? unnecessary?  Again, many thanks.

Comment: @pichael: It would depend on the crowd. I suppose it is a good explanation if the crowd is made of people knowing a bit about logic - but not too much about logic. However in the year 2012 it cannot go unaccompanied by its solution.

Comment: @Michael: I'm terribly sorry for hijacking this thread like this! :-)

Comment: @Asaf: No problem. But I was slightly puzzled when I saw that I had 13 notifications in my inbox... :-)

Comment: I'm sure you're probably exhausted from this thread, but maybe I could ask a beginner type question. How can a model itself be countable and yet not have a function which is a bijection with $\omega$? Thanks,

Comment: @Andrew The point is the meaning of a model "having a bijection with $\omega$" or plainly "what is a model".  You might think of the model having a list of names for objects and not having a name for the bijection.

Comment: Thanks, Michael