# Is there is limit to what $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be in a ctm?

Tags: set-theory

Is there is limit to what $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be in a countable transitive model?

How large can be the value of the continuum in a countable transitive (standard) model of ZFC?  For instance, if we wanted to consider the case where $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{\omega_1}$, where would the $\aleph_1$ smaller cardinals come from, after all, the model is only countable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there exists any transitive model of ZFC, there exists a countable submodel by Lowenheim-Skolem.  This countable submodel may not be transitive, but it is well-founded, so by Mostowski collapse it is isomorphic to a countable transitive model $M$.

Using forcing, you can then construct generic extensions of $M$ (which are also countable transitive models) in which $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be "arbitrarily large".  More precisely, let us suppose for simplicity that $M$ satisfies GCH (this can be arranged by a class forcing, or by replacing $M$ with $L^M$).  Then if $\kappa\in M$ is any ordinal such that $$M\vDash\text{"$\kappa$ is a cardinal of uncountable cofinality"},$$ there is a generic extension $M[G]$ of $M$ which has the same cardinals as $M$ and which satisfies $M[G]\vDash 2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$.  In particular, if (say) $M\vDash \kappa=\aleph_{\omega_1}$, then $M[G]$ is a countable transitive model in which $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega_1}$.

Note, however, that this does *not* mean that there actually are uncountably many cardinals in $M[G]$ below $2^{\aleph_0}$, any more than the fact that $M[G]\vDash 2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$ means $M[G]$ actually contains uncountably many real numbers.  What it means is that $M[G]$ *thinks* there are uncountably many cardinals less than what it thinks is $2^{\aleph_0}$.  From the perspective of the outside universe, all of these "cardinals" below $2^{\aleph_0}$ are actually just countable ordinals (as is the cardinal $M$ thinks is $2^{\aleph_0}$), and there are only countably many of them.  However, $M[G]$ doesn't know this, because no bijection from these sets to $\omega$ is an element of $M[G]$.

If you are still confused about this, you may find [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox) or the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312011/countable-transitive-model-of-zfc) helpful.

Comment: Thks for the references.  I "get" that M[G] lacks many bijections the outside world knows of, hence assigns the role of "cardinals" below $2^{\aleph_0}$ to various countable ordinals.  Here's what still bothers me: Suppose outsiders examine those (countably many) countable ordinals (i.e the M[G] cardinals) and determine their sup (in the outside world), call it beta - (still a countable ordinal).  Then we say to folks in M[G] world, "Point to $aleph_{beta}" and they respond with (say) aleph_{omega_1}.  Does our "gotcha" question fail because we lack explicit simpler notation to express beta?

Comment: Right, there can be no way to define $\beta$ such that the following two properties hold simultaneously: $M[G]$ thinks $\beta$ is the same thing as the full universe does (our definition is "absolute" for $M[G]$), and we can prove in ZFC that $\beta$ is countable.  (For instance, $\omega_1$ is a definable ordinal which fails the first criterion, and $\omega_1^L$ is a definable ordinal which fails the second criterion.)  If we could give such a definition of $\beta$, then since $M[G]$ is a model of ZFC, it would know that $\beta$ is countable.

Comment: So, we might be able to "point out" $\beta$ to $M[G]$, but not in a way that is strong enough to let $M[G]$ tell that $\beta$ has to be countable.  Or we might not even be able to point it out at all--there's no reason in general to expect that $\beta$ is even definable in the language of set theory without parameters.

Comment: Yes, OK - I appreciate the follow-up comments, that clarifies things.